# bit manipulation (divide whiteout dividing )

Tags: bitmap, bit-manipulation, probability, bit, bit-shift

You have a processor that supports the following commands:

```
mac(x,y,z) = x*y+z
```

H(Rx) = high bits of reg Rx

L(Rx) = low bits of Rx

The processor can execute two instructions per cycle.
You have several registers need.

Do the following function:

```
( ( (a – b) >> 3 ) + c – d + 4) << 2.
```

So I tried:

```
r1 = (b,-1,a) .  r2 =(d,-1,c).
```

the hardest part that I can't Solve is the division by 8 (>>3).

Comment: `mac` doesn't divide at all, so the key must be `H`, which does divide. But you have not given enough information, the number of low bits is critical, since it determines how much `H` divides by.

Comment: Using commands and set int.